# How to extract the latest row

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
Item    Serial_No   Grade   Size    Location    Date
CQ35    A243911     4   36  A           20110127
CQ35    A243911     4   36  B           20110329
CQ35    A243911     4   36  C           20110330
CQ38    A244567     3   38  A           20110127
CQ35    A244567     3   38  B           20110128
CQ38    A244567     3   38  C           20110129
CQ35    A244567     3   38  D           20110130
CQ40    A244568     3   41  A           20110127
CQ40    A244568     3   41  B           20110129
CQ36    A244570         2   37  A           20110125
```

The expected results shd look like this using SQL:

```
Item    Serial_No   Grade   Size    Location    Date
CQ35    A243911     4   36  C           20110330
CQ35    A244567     3   38  D           20110130
CQ40    A244568     3   41  B           20110129
CQ36    A244570         2   37  A           20110125
```

I'm trying to extract the latest row of each Serial No.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE : with date

```
select * 
from table as outertable
where date = (select max(date) from table where Serial_No = outertable.Serial_No)
```

The trick here is to do comparison in the range of Serial_No only, and the way to achieve this is with a [Correlated Subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) as shown here.

Comment: Error. The msg is:-Error: SQL5001 - Column qualifier or table OUTER undefined.

Comment: @bob that's because outer is a reserved word, have changed it now

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that there is only one entry for each date and serial number.

```
SELECT MyTable.*
FROM MyTable
INNER JOIN (SELECT SerialNo, MAX(Date)
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY SerialNo) AS MyTableLatest ON MyTable.SerialNo = MyTableLatest.SerialNo
        AND MyTable.Date = MyTableLatest.Date
```

Comment: looks overly complecated for just a part of the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE Date
IN (
SELECT MAX( Date )
FROM table
GROUP BY Serial_No
)
```

Comment: it selects all rows with dates that are a maxdate somewhere,  completeley independent of serialnr

Comment: More precisely, this would break if several products had the same Date but different Serial_No.